# DirectoryNotFoundException on building first Hololens App

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, hololens, hololens-emulator

I'm new and try to do the 100 Tutorial.

I keep getting this Error on building with unity:

> DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\Platforms\UAP\10.0.14393.0\Platform.xml"

When i look up the path, there is no "Platform" directory in 10 (maybe because of the SDK change from 10.0.10586 to 10.0.14393).

I've already checked the answers of similar topics for example [this](https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/2374/unity-not-exporting-visual-studio-correctly)

Compared to that, i've set up everything right:
[image: Visual Studio Setup]

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a result of a bad installation.

I came across the-same exact problem few months ago when I when I wanted to a simple Windows 10 build test. This is what worked for me in order.

**1**.Uninstall Visual Studio

**2**.Restart computer

**3**.Install Visual Studio

Do **not** try to change the default install directory during installation.

Make sure that everything under *Universal Windows App Development Tools* is checked. One exception is anything with prefix "Windows 8".

**4**.Restart computer once more to make sure that no Visual Studio service is running in the background.

**5**.Install Windows 10 SDK from [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=822845).

While installing *Windows 10 SDK*, if you get a message that says the SDK is already installed and up-to-date then you are done. Otherwise continue.

When finished, check if *C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Platforms* is available.

It should like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I thought Installing the Windows 10 SDK through VS is enough, but installing it external did the trick.

Comment: You are welcome. It took only "3" days to find this out. Happy coding!

Comment: Do you need Windows 10 to run an app on Hololens? I'm having trouble with running on device, although I was finally able to export from Unity to VS.

Comment: @JacoboKoenig Yes. You need Windows 10. The reason for this is that you need Widows 10 to build for UWP and Hololens needs UWP. Don't waste your time if you don't have Windows 10. You can't build it.

Comment: @Programmer I was afraid of that. Thanks.. I asked that on another post, if you answer there Id be happy to accept your answer